# Override default phtml files?

Tags: magento-1.8, layout, template, customer-account

I want to override customer/address/edit.phtml and customer/form/address.phtml files for my module, In my module layout.xml I used the code below for edit.phtml but didn't override:

```
<customer_address_form translate="label">
    <reference name="customer.address.edit">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>mycompany/mymodule/customer/address/edit.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_address_form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

replaced my code with below and work as well

```
<customer_address_form>
    <reference name="customer_address_edit">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>mycompany/mymodule/customer/address/edit.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_address_form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try it following way

```
<customer_account_edit>
    <reference name="customer_edit">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>mycompany/mymodule/customer/address/edit.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_account_edit>
```

after that, don't forget to clear magento cache.

Comment: changed but still not working!

Comment: Clear magento cache.

Comment: cleared, also cache is disable